# Calculate values only for specific values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have function that calculates difference between current and previous rows

Here it is

```
function distanceDifference() {
    var rowsDistance = $('#tbody tr');
    for (j = 1; j < rowsDistance.length; j++) {

        // Get the rows
        var previousDistanceRow = rowsDistance.eq(j - 1);
        var currentDistanceRow = rowsDistance.eq(j);

        var previousDistance = previousDistanceRow.find('td').eq(5).text();
        var currentDistance = currentDistanceRow.find('td').eq(5).text();

        //alert(previousDistance);

        var difference = currentDistance - previousDistance;
        //alert(difference);
        currentDistanceRow.find('td').eq(6).text(difference);

    }
}
```

It works well for all values

But I have column

```
<td id="dataType">@data.Datatype</td>
```

Value of it can be 0,1,2

I need to calculate difference only if it `===2`

I try to do it like this

```
function distanceDifference() {
    var rowsDistance = $('#tbody tr');
    for (j = 1; j < rowsDistance.length; j++) {
        var value = $('#dataType').text();
        if (value === 2) {
        // Get the rows
        var previousDistanceRow = rowsDistance.eq(j - 1);
        var currentDistanceRow = rowsDistance.eq(j);

        var previousDistance = previousDistanceRow.find('td').eq(5).text();
        var currentDistance = currentDistanceRow.find('td').eq(5).text();

        //alert(previousDistance);

        var difference = currentDistance - previousDistance;
        //alert(difference);
        currentDistanceRow.find('td').eq(6).text(difference);
      }
    }
}
```

but it not works. How I need to write code correctly?

Comment: what is `====2` ?

Comment: 2 is value that can be in this column@KoushikChatterjee

Comment: but why `====` ?? either it will be `==` or `===` right? or is that just a typo?

Comment: Where are you see. `====` I wrote  `====` @KoushikChatterjee

Comment: here: **I need to calculate difference only if it ====2**

Comment: Edit my question@KoushikChatterjee

Comment: Oho, good. thanks for the edit :)

Comment: When I try to get 2 from `id=dataType` it not find it@KoushikChatterjee

Answer (score 2):

Use `if (value == 2)` instead of `if (value === 2)`.

Because equality operator `===` compares also the operands data types.

But the data type for the value `'2'` is `string` and you comparing with `integer` `2`

Operator `==` will compare only value `2 == 2`, without comparing the operands data types!

Comment: Which shouldn't be a good practice in my opinion. Better to convert the string into a Number and strictly compare it with the other

Answer (score 0):

Even though a non-strict comparison would work it is - in my opinion - better practice to validate and convert user input to a specific data type.

So if you expect the users input to be an integer, use this

```
var value = parseInt( $('#dataType').text(), 10 );
```

If you expect it to be a number with a floating point, use this instead:

```
var value = parseFloat( $('#dataType').text() )
```

Then you can use a strict comparison like you already did.

But always validate if the user input has the right format.

Comment: When I try to get 2 from id=dataType it not find it

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: When I write `console.log(value);` after `var value = $('#dataType ').html();` it gets only `0`

Comment: What does `console.log( typeof value );` give you?

Comment: It gives me `string`

Comment: Exactly, because text in HTML elements is always a string, not a number. Even though it is intended to just be a number. Therefore you need to convert `$( '#dataType' ).html()` to a number with `parseInt( $( '#dataType' ).html() )`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150953/discussion-between-sukhomlin-eugene-and-lumio).

Answer (score 0):

So trouble was in that I get only first value from column

Here is valid code

```
function distanceDifference() {
    var rowsDistance = $('#tbody tr');
    for (j = 1; j < rowsDistance.length; j++) {
        //var value = parseInt($('.dataType ').html());
        var test = $('.dataType');
        if (parseInt($(test[j]).html()) === 2) {
        // Get the rows
        var previousDistanceRow = rowsDistance.eq(j - 1);
        var currentDistanceRow = rowsDistance.eq(j);
        var previousDistance = previousDistanceRow.find('td').eq(5).text();
        var currentDistance = currentDistanceRow.find('td').eq(5).text();
        var difference = currentDistance - previousDistance;
        currentDistanceRow.find('td').eq(6).text(difference);
     }
    }
}
```